# What are SQL Server Securables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, security, ssms, terminology

I migrated two applications to the new server. One of the them works without any issues but the other ran into back end sql permission problems like

> **The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object
>   ‘aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion’**

I could find figure why one application would work and the other would not. They both run under the same application pool but uses different database. I didnont have to do anything for the one that to work, for the other I had to grant permission on [Network Service] user for each table, stored procedure which the application access.

Well I have resolved the problem now by making the two databases securables for Network Service. I dont know why I had to do this for one application while the other does not need it. My question is

**What is SQL Server Securable in SQL Server Management Studio?** You basically access them when you click on user -> Properties then go to second page on the left.

**What is it used for?** *What is its proper use?*

From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189679%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Securables
>
> ```
> Lists the securables on which specific permissions have been granted or denied to  this principal.
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A securable is anything that can have permissions granted, denied, or revoked on in SQL Server.  It's basically **"something you can secure"**.

Think about it like this:  Your car is a securable.  You would have to have been given keys (*permissions*) to access your car (*securable*).

*A securable is anything that can be accessible or inaccessible.*

Take a look at this [BOL reference on Securables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190401%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  Under the three scopes of securables (server, database, schema) you can see a listing of the contained ones.  Here is the list of securables (taken directly from BOL, but for reference):

> **Server Scope Securables**
>
> - Endpoint
> - Login
> - Database
>
> **Database Scope Securables**
>
> - User
> - Role
> - Application role
> - Assembly
> - Message Type
> - Route
> - Service
> - Remote Service Binding
> - Fulltext Catalog
> - Certificate
> - Asymmetric Key
> - Symmetric Key
> - Contract
> - Schema
>
> **Schema Scope Securables**
>
> - Type
> - XML Schema Collection
> - Object
>
>   - Aggregate
>   - Function
>   - Procedure
>   - Queue
>   - Synonym
>   - Table
>   - View