# Script server level user securables onto another server

Tags: sql-server, scripting

I have restored a backup of the live DB on a test SQL Server VM.

Then I scripted the server level SQL users and restored them on the test SQL Server and fixed the orphaned user situation.

But the user securables were not scripted - is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possibly relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779202/14868997

Answer (score 0):

User securables are more relevant at user level hence, you need to check them for each database one by one. Either you can find them for one specific user within a database or for all the users in that database.

I check them using below script for one specified user:

```
select USER_NAME(p.grantee_principal_id) AS principal_name,
dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc,
p.class_desc,
OBJECT_NAME(p.major_id) AS object_name,
p.permission_name,
p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
from sys.database_permissions p
inner JOIN sys.database_principals dp
on p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
where USER_NAME(p.grantee_principal_id) = 'db_user'
```

If you want to check for all the users in the database, just remove the last where clause as below:

```
select USER_NAME(p.grantee_principal_id) AS principal_name,
dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc,
p.class_desc,
OBJECT_NAME(p.major_id) AS object_name,
p.permission_name,
p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
from sys.database_permissions p
inner JOIN sys.database_principals dp
on p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
```

You need to check `class_desc` column having value `OBJECT_OR_COLUMN`

I am not very sure however you may use the same script for server level securables being in master database however that should already be taken care by login transfer using [sp_help_revlogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances)

For more details on securables, you may check this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29893/136766).

Hope this helps.